# WebView Shows blank page when opening payment sites - Lollipop

Tags: android, webview

I'm facing problem Loading URL to a WebView it always show's blank page, and I can't see any error in my LogCat. It works fine on below 5.0 [Lollipop] devices, The error occurs only in Lollipop devices. I tried many solutions present in StackOverflow but none of them worked. 
Below is the final Code that i ended up with.
Site I'm trying to Load is : **https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/**
Any Help would be appreciated thanks a lot.

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by shetty on 4/18/2015.
 */
public class WebPageTest extends Activity {

    WebView webView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page);
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

       // webView.clearSslPreferences();
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            webView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
        }
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                Log.d("CHECK", "onReceivedSslError");
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebPageTest.this);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                String message = "Certificate error.";
                switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                    case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                        message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                        message = "The certificate has expired.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                        message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                        message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                        break;
                }
                message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";
                alertDialog.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(message);
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("CHECK", "Button ok pressed");
                        // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                        handler.proceed();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("CHECK", "Button cancel pressed");
                        handler.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to figure this out. The thing about your site and the one I was struggling with is that they are trying to occupy full screen height. My webview (and I think yours as well) had layout_height="wrap_content", and although it had proper height because of positioning inside relative layout, when targeting sdk 21 webview was reporting 0 height to the page resulting all its elements collapse to 0 height as well. All you need to do is to change layout_height of the webview to match_parent.

Pro tip for developers struggling with webview rendering problems. Use webview remote debugging https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging
It can save a lot of time when dealing with problems like this.

Comment: Thanks buddy, resolved this problem anyway, using an example GutHub Project. but this is the exact solution for my problem. Thanks for your help 
!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of changes in webview for lolipop, maybe this helps.

Android 5.0 changes the default behavior for your app.

If your app targets API level 21 or higher:
The system blocks mixed content and third party cookies by default. To allow mixed content and third party cookies, use the setMixedContentMode() and setAcceptThirdPartyCookies() methods respectively.
The system now intelligently chooses portions of the HTML document to draw. This new default behavior helps to reduce memory footprint and increase performance. If you want to render the whole document at once, disable this optimization by calling enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw().
If your app targets API levels lower than 21: The system allows mixed content and third party cookies, and always renders the whole document at once.

Source: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorWebView

Comment: Thanks for responding. I Tried all three and Updated my question. but still facing the same issue.