# Inside Webview redirect link from http to Https Payment Link is not working in Lollipop and above 5.0 and its showing blank in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
            }
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

            if (url != null && (url.contains("http://195.154.151.27/DIS/OnlinePolicyReports.aspx") || url.contains("http://195.154.151.27/dis/Files") )
                    ) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }

            else {
                if (!pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.show();
                }

                return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("on finish");
            if ((pd!=null) && pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
             //   pd=null;
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                       SslError error) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.proceed();
        }

    });
```

Comment: hello can you pls check log cat and post any error or somethng if you are getting .. i mean security exception or anything ?

Comment: Its not showing error, when i click on pay in webview its showing blank and no error on log cat

Comment: Finally i got the solution at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720231/webview-shows-blank-page-when-opening-payment-sites-lollipop